# How Can I Match Swift 4 KVO on Non-Objective-C Type?

Tags: swift4, key-value-observing

I have a `Result` type that I use in asynchronous processes:

```swift
internal enum Result<T> {

    case success(T)

    case failure(Error)

}
```

I also have a `APIDataResultContext` that I use to pass data between `Operation` subclasses:

```swift
internal final class APIDataResultContext: NSObject {

    // MARK: Properties

    private let lock = NSLock()

    private var _result: Result<Data>!

    internal var result: Result<Data>! {
        get {
            lock.lock()
            let temp = _result
            lock.unlock()
            return temp
        } 
        set {
            lock.lock()
            _result = newValue
            lock.unlock()
        }
    }

}
```

In my unit tests, I need to determine when `result` has been set in an `APIDataResultContext` instance. I can't use KVO because my `Result<T>` type cannot be marked as `dynamic` since it can't be represented in Objective-C.

I don't know of another way that will allow me to monitor when `result` is changed other than using a closure property or a `Notification`, which I would prefer not to do. I will resort to one of the two if necessary, though.

What other way(s) can I monitor for a change of `result`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding a closure property to `APIDataResultContext`:

```swift
internal final class APIDataResultContext {

    // MARK: Properties

    internal var resultChanged: (()->())?

    private let lock = NSLock()

    private var _result: Result<Data>!

    internal var result: Result<Data>! {
        get {
            lock.lock()
            let temp = _result
            lock.unlock()
            return temp
        }
        set {
            lock.lock()
            _result = newValue
            lock.unlock()
            resultChanged?()
        }
    }
```

}

I use the closure in my tests to determine when `result` has been changed:

```swift
internal func testNeoWsFeedOperationWithDatesPassesDataToResultContext() {
    let operationExpectation = expectation(description: #function)
    let testData = DataUtility().data(from: "Hello, world!")
    let mockSession = MockURLSession()
    let testContext = APIDataResultContext()
    testContext.resultChanged = {
        operationExpectation.fulfill()
        guard let result = testContext.result else {
            XCTFail("Expected result")
            return
        }
        switch result {
        case .failure(_):
            XCTFail("Expected data")
        case .success(let data):
            XCTAssertEqual(data, testData, "Expected '\(testData)'")
        }
    }
    NeoWsFeedOperation(context: testContext, sessionType: mockSession, apiKey: testAPIKey, startDate: testDate, endDate: testDate).start()
    mockSession.completionHandler?(testData, nil, nil)
    wait(for: [operationExpectation], timeout: 2)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've already solved this issue (and what you did is probably what I'd do), but there's probably still value in providing a literal answer for the title question: How *can* you use KVO on a non-Objective-C type?

As it turns out, it's not too difficult to do, although it is somewhat ugly. Basically, you need to create an Objective-C property that is typed `Any` with the same Objective-C name as the Swift name of the real property. Then, you put `willSet` and `didSet` handlers on the real property that call the appropriate KVO methods for the Objective-C property. So, something like:

```
@objc(result) private var _resultKVO: Any { return self.result }
internal var result: Result<Data>! {
    willSet { self.willChangeValue(for: \._resultKVO) }
    didSet { self.didChangeValue(for: \._resultKVO) }
}
```

(For the sake of simplicity, I'm assuming that `result` is your stored property, and removing the lock and the private property from the equation)

The caveat is that you will have to use `_resultKVO` instead of `result` when constructing key paths to observe, which means that if this needs to be observable from outside the object, you can't make `_resultKVO` `private`, and you'll have to clutter up your class's interface with it. But so it goes.

Again, I probably wouldn't do this for your particular use case (and if you did, you could obviously fire the notifications in `result`'s `set` rather than having to bother with `willSet` and `didSet`), but in some cases this can be useful, and it's good to have an answer describing how to do it as a reference.

Comment: I wish this worked (what I really wish for is NATIVE Swift-based KVO but one can dream...) but I was not able to get this to work from the Swift side of things. When you attempt to observe it using the Swift 4 keypath stuff it crashes when trying to convert `_resultKVO` to `Result<Data>` (in my case it was to `String` through generics).

Comment: @DeanKelly I've done this sort of thing plenty of times. If you could create a question showing your specific problem as well as the crash you're getting, and tag me on a comment attached to that question, I could take a crack at figuring out what's going wrong in your case.

Comment: I see now. Was attempting to observe the non-private variable which is needed in the generics to provide the type. I can reconfigure the surrounding API to handle an `Observable` and do this instead. Not the prettiest thing but it does work.